# ListFragment ListItems appear but not their content

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-cursoradapter

I am scotched on a probably trivial problem. I want to get the list of phone numbers for a contact in a ListFragment. The items of the list appear in good number but not the text inside. At the moment to get rid of any other problem, I only load the fragment in main activity in a layout container and start the loader with a previously known lookupKey.
The loader returns the correct values for phone number (info from Log.d messages) and also in the correct number.

Here is my item layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#AAAAAA"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/telNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000BB"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Adapter

```js
    package com.zoraldia.android.zcontacts;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created  on 07/09/15.
 */
public class PhoneAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater; // Stores the layout inflater

    public PhoneAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, null, 0);

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        //TextView telType;
        TextView telNumber;

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View itemLayout =
                mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tel_list_item, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        //  holder.telType = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.telType);
        holder.telNumber = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.telNumber);
        itemLayout.setTag(holder);
        return itemLayout;
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        // final String telType = cursor.getString(3);
        final String telNumber = cursor.getString(2);

    }

    @Override
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
 
        return super.swapCursor(newCursor);
    }

    /**
     * An override of getCount that simplifies accessing the Cursor. If the Cursor is null,
     * getCount returns zero. As a result, no test for Cursor == null is needed.
     */

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (getCursor() == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return super.getCount();
    }
}
```

My ListFragment

```js
package com.zoraldia.android.zcontacts;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created on 07/09/15.
 */
public class PhoneListViewFragment extends ListFragment implements
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    // Defines a tag for identifying log entries
    private static final String TAG = "PhoneListFragment";
    private static final String msg = "PhoneListFragment";
    private String[] mSelectionArguments = {"0r7-555555"};

    private PhoneAdapter phoneAdapter;

    public PhoneListViewFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        phoneAdapter = new PhoneAdapter(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(phoneAdapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(ContactsQueryTel.QUERY_ID, null, this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Uri contentUri = ContactsQueryTel.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] selectionArgs = mSelectionArguments;
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                contentUri,
                ContactsQueryTel.PROJECTION,
                ContactsQueryTel.SELECTION,
                selectionArgs,
                ContactsQueryTel.SORT_ORDER
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        //The following is just for log
        String type;
        String number;
        if (data.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                //          type = Integer.toString(data.getInt(3));
                number = data.getString(2);
                Log.d(msg, " Row _data 2: " + data.getString(1) + " number=" + data.getString(2));
            } while (data.moveToNext());
        }

        phoneAdapter.swapCursor(data);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        phoneAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }


    public interface ContactsQueryTel {
        int QUERY_ID = 1;

        Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

        String[] PROJECTION = {
                ContactsContract.Data._ID,
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA1,//Number, String int
        };
        // Defines the selection clause
        String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY +
            " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = " +
            "'" + CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";

        // Defines the array to hold the search criteria
        String[] mSelectionArgs = {"0r1-3B454D313345514B4339314B"};
        String SORT_ORDER = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE;
    }
}
```

and eventually what the log returns

> 09-07 15:47:51.660  29989-29989/com.example.android.fragments D/PhoneListFragment﹕ Row _data 2: vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2 number=080-8080
>   09-07 15:47:51.660  29989-29989/com.example.android.fragments D/PhoneListFragment﹕ Row _data 2: vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2 number=999-070

Hope someone can help.

Comment: In _CursorAdapter.bindView_ you seem not to set telNumber variable into TextView - only read holder reference from View.getTag(). Should you do also _TextView.setText(telNumber)_?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid of me! In the bindView it should be **holder.telNumber.setText(cursor.getString(2))** instead of final **String telNumber = cursor.getString(2);**